# Returning variables and while True loop

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

I want to execute code in one function that asks the user for 2 numbers, and return both of them. Then in the second function I want to "import" these 2 values and print them to the user, and add them to an array. However, this only seems to work after every 2 loops in the `while True` loop (if you execute the code, you'll see what I mean).

```
def function1():
    var1 = raw_input("Please enter a number")
    var2 = raw_input("Please enter another number")
    return var1,var2

def function2():
    var1,var2 = function1()
    print 1,2

while True:
    function1()
    function2()
```

Thanks for any help"

Comment: you are calling `function1` twice every loop: once from the loop itself and once from `function2`... does that help?

Comment: besides, your code doesn't depend on `var1` and `var2` - it always prints `1 2`

Comment: and you never add them to any list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
def function1():
    var1 = raw_input("Please enter a number")
    var2 = raw_input("Please enter another number")
    return var1,var2

def function2():
    var1,var2 = function1()
    print var1,var2

while True:
    function2()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need:

```
while True:
    function2()
```

The reason for this is that function2 itself already calls function1 - you don't want to call it twice per iteration.

You should also check whether function1 is printing the right values!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `function2` in your infinite loop:

```
while True:
    function2()
```

`function2` is calling `function1` in its body, so it will manage the input user. Plus, your `function2` definition should be:

```
def function2():
    var1,var2 = function1()
    print var1, var2
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `function1` directly, you get the two variables back but don't do anything with them.

When you call `function2`, you assign the two variables from `function1` to local names in `function2`, then print two integers (not that actual variables) and leave the function.

If you want to add them to an array, you need to do that:

```
array = []
while True:
    array.extend(function1())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call function1 the first time, the function returns the two numbers you entered, but they aren't stored anywhere. When you then call function2, function1 is called **again**, which makes the user input **new** numbers for the variables 1 and 2. If you want to import the numbers you already got from function1, function2 needs to take two numbers as an argument. Moreover, you always print the numbers 1 and 2, no matter what the input is, so you would probably want to print var1,var2 instead of 1,2 in function2.

Also, you don't add the numbers to an array. You probably want something like this:

```
def function1():
    var1 = raw_input("Please enter a number")
    var2 = raw_input("Please enter another number")
    return var1,var2

def function2(var1, var2):
    print var1,var2

#Make an empty array
array = []

while True:
    numbers = function1()
    function2(numbers[0], numbers[1])

    #Append the two numbers to the array
    array.append(numbers[0])
    array.append(numbers[1])

    print "The array now contains: " + ', '.join(array)
```